# Logic Pro X not receiving audio but can record with Quicktime Player

Tags: logic-pro

I feel like I must have something either stupid, or really obscure wrong here.

I have an old Presonus Firebox interface I have used successfully many times, in fact I used it with Logic last weekend and it was fine.

Today I am trying to record audio from it into Logic and nothing shows up in the input monitors, and if I hit record the track just records silence.

If I open the macos Sound Preferences I can see the level meters *there* showing audio coming in from the Firebox. If I open Quicktime Player and start a new audio recording with Firebox as the input source it works fine.

[image: macos Sound Preferences]

So it must be something in Logic. AFAICT I have the basics set up right...

I have the Firebox selected in Audio Preferences:

[image: Logic Audio preferences]

I have Input 1 (this is definitely the right one) selected on my recording track:

[image: channel strip]

I also seem to have the same problem in Adobe Audition.

Why would the audio input work in system/Quicktime but not in my DAWs?

I have changed the macos system Sound Preferences input back to "Internal Microphone" in case it was 'holding' on to it somehow.  But that did not fix anything.

In the system Audio MIDI Setup dialog the Firebox looks like:
[image]

I wonder a bit about the input channels being greyed out. If Quicktime Player was recording the Master input while Logic is attaching to a disabled channel "1" that would explain things I guess.

But if so, why is it like that? And how to fix it? What could have happened since approx last weekend that messed up the driver(?) for the Firebox.

Forgot to mention... I have rebooted the macbook and restarted Logic a couple of times.

I am on macos Mojave 10.14.6 and Logic Pro X 10.2.2

Comment: [RoaringApps](https://roaringapps.com/app/logic-pro-x) mentions 10.3.1 is minimum required for High Sierra. Current version is 10.5.1 - time to update, I'd think. Also see https://support.presonus.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006825371--Apple-MacOS-10-14-Mojave-and-iOS-12-compatibility-statement

Comment: I had to stop using my Firebox when I got a new MacBook Pro, no firewire connections on the new machine lol”l. Also the Firebox is discontinued and the last installer/driver for Mac was 10.7, Lion, about 7 os’s prior to your current one. I’m guessing you have a machine with FireWire but I think updates to the os and to Logic Pro are likely why it’s not working anymore.

Comment: I have a Firewire->Thunderbolt adapter and have used this chain successfully with my macbook in the past...

Comment: Is the o/p port working fine?